# Zend Framework - Controlling Access to controllers

Tags: zend-framework

I have a website with 3 different user roles: guest(unregistered), member and admin.

I would like to restrict access to controllers as follows.

> AuthController -> guest, member, admin
>
> AdminController -> admin
>
> MemberController -> member

Is there a simple way to do it without using Zend_Acl? I don't really understand how to actually use Zend_Acl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this tutorial](http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/20/zend-authentication-and-authorization-tutorial-with-zend_auth-and-zend_acl/) very useful for implementing a simple Auth & ACL scheme.

It invoves creating a Front Controller Plugin & custom Zend_ACL class.

EDIT: To answer the question in your comment

You can define the resources without the action part

```
    // Add some resources in the form controller
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('error'));
    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('auth'));

    // Allow guests to see the error, login and index pages
    $this->allow('guest', 'error');
    $this->allow('guest', 'auth');
```

and don't check for action in front plugin

```
if(!$acl->isAllowed($user->role, $request->getControllerName())) {
```

I didn't tested it but it should work.

Comment: Thank you, that link is nice and easy to understand. One question though. Instead of typing "new Zend_Acl_Resource('auth::login')" for every single controller/action i have. Can i use "auth::all" to specify all the actions in a controller?

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a [proposal](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=39025) for an official frontcontroller plugin, but sadly not much has come out of that. The code is still available though, and there is a [tutorial on the Zend DevZone blog.](http://devzone.zend.com/1258/zend_acl-and-mvc-integration-part-i-basic-use/)

It might be worth it to check out the changes upcoming for ZF 2.0, they changed the Access parts according to some of the replies to the proposal.